# Bind "step" to input using Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I had to dig into knockout for an old project and finally got some stuff working, but I'm having trouble with the `step` attribute on my `input` element.

```
<!-- ko if: guaranteedQuantity > 1 -->
    <input type="number" min="0" data-bind="value: quantity, step: guaranteedQuantity" />
<!-- /ko-->
```

`guaranteedQuantity` is gotten from my viewmodel and the `if`-condition works well with it, so I know it has the correct value. I'm just having troubles binding it to `step` – am I using `data-bind` incorrectly?

Comment: `data-bind="value: quantity, attr: { step: guaranteedQuantity  }"`

Comment: Thanks, this works!

Answer (score 1):

As explained by haim770 in the comment, you can use `attr` binding to assign value to `step` attribute on the input.

```
<!-- ko if: guaranteedQuantity > 1 -->
    <input type="number" min="0" data-bind="value: quantity, attr: { step: guaranteedQuantity }" />
<!-- /ko-->
```